# Gimp fails to open

Tags: gimp

A few weeks ago, Gimp was working fine, then I tried to open it, the icon flashes away a bit, and then closes again, one time there appeared a dialog which told me that Gimp had unexpectedly closed, and I could choose wether I wanted to restart the program or leave it closed. Restarting had no effect.

Then I started Gimp via terminal, and got this output:

```
(gimp:26651): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_valist: object class 'GeglConfig' has no property named 'cache-size'

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x178E180 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:dissolve-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x178E650 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:behind-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x178EE90 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:multiply-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x178F1A0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:screen-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x178F570 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:overlay-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x178F9A0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:difference-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x178FD60 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:addition-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1790130 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:subtract-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17904F0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:darken-only-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1790940 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:lighten-only-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1790D50 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:hue-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1791080 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:saturation-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17914E0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:color-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1791950 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:value-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17920F0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:divide-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1792570 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:dodge-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17928E0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:burn-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1792D30 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:hardlight-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17930D0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:softlight-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17934D0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:grain-extract-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1793930 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:grain-merge-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1793CE0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:color-erase-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17940D0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:erase-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17944F0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:replace-mode"

(gimp:26651): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x17948C0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:anti-erase-mode"
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5258: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/GIMP_Orange/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5259: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/GIMP_Orange/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5260: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/Dark/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5261: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/Dark/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5262: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/Dark/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5265: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/GIMP_Orange/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5266: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/GIMP_Orange/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5267: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/Dark/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5268: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/Dark/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5269: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/Dark/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5272: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/GIMP_Orange/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5273: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/GIMP_Orange/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5274: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/Dark/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5275: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/Dark/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5276: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/Dark/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
/home/peter/.gimp-2.8/themes/Darker GIMP_Orange small/imagerc:5279: Kan afbeelding in pixmap_pad: ‘../Decor/icons/Dark/dialogs/stock-image-16.png’ niet vinden
Segmentatiefout (geheugendump gemaakt)
```

The last half are errors from a theme I had installed.

I have tried reinstalling, purging the installation via terminal and via Synaptic, but I still get the same result.

Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Is it working ok?

Comment: Actually no window is opened at all..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that you installed an icon pack or theme that doesn't let you run `gimp` if that's the case don't use that theme and report it to the creator.

Try deleting `gimp` and reinstalling it with

```
sudo apt-get purge gimp --auto-remove
```

then just delete the Gimp config files

```
rm -rf .gimp-2.8/
```

and reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

let me know if this worked, hope this helps

Comment: Weird, I thought that purging the program would remove the .gimp-2.8/ folder. Anyways, it worked like a charm, thank you very much for a really quick answer!

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: Actually, just purging  the `.gimp-2.8/` folder is enough in 99% of the cases. It is even bettre to just rename it, so that some of its contents can be added back to the new profile.