# GIMP doesn't work

Tags: 16.04

After several happy years GIMP doesn't work any more. Clicks on the icons in the top line (like "Datei" in my German version) remain without any reaction.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

Calling gimp gave the following messages:

```
(gimp:2971): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_valist: object class 'GeglConfig' has no property named 'cache-size'

(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1ABE260 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:dissolve-mode"    
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1ABE4F0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:behind-mode"    
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1ABE8B0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:multiply-mode"    
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1ABF5A0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:screen-mode"    
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1ABF950 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:overlay-mode"    
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1ABFD80 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:difference-mode"    
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC0140 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:addition-mode"    
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC0580 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:subtract-mode"    
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC0970 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:darken-only-mode"    
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC0DC0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:lighten-only-mode"    
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC1200 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:hue-mode"   
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC1560 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:saturation-mode"    
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC19C0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:color-mode"
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC1DB0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:value-mode"
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC21A0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:divide-mode"
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC2620 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:dodge-mode"
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC2A10 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:burn-mode"
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC2E40 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:hardlight-mode"
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC38F0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:softlight-mode"
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC3D10 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:grain-extract-mode"
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC4170 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:grain-merge-mode"
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC45A0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:color-erase-mode"
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC4940 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:erase-mode"    
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC4DA0 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:replace-mode"
(gimp:2971): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x1AC5140 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:anti-erase-mode"
```

Comment: I don't see a problem. These are all WARNINGS, those are notifications to developers and maintainers of gimp. Almost ALL of these (except the 1st one) are the same issue so basically it is 1 warning,

Comment: Did you change something related to fonts?  This duplicate seems to suggest so, fix was to purge gimp and reinstall (a bit drastic though ): https://askubuntu.com/questions/931640/gimp-fails-to-open  Bug repot https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/1576977